# How to calculate the medial axis?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, medial-axis

Does anyone know how to calculate the medial axis for two given curves?

Medial axis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis

Here is the shape I need to calculate it for:
[image]

I drew in the medial axis myself, the dark black line, but I need to be able to calculate it dynamically.

Here is the applet and code of what I have done so far:
http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~jstrauss6/3451/sample/

The known variables are:
-pt A, B, C, D
-radii of red, green, and black circles
-pt Q and R (just outside the picture), the black circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `C1` and `C2` be centers of circles with radii `r1` and `r2`. The medial axis (minus the two center points) of the figure made of the two circles is the set of points `M` satisfying

```
|M - C1| - r1 = |M - C2| - r2
```

which implies

```
|M - C1| - |M - C2| = r1 - r2
|M - C1|^2 + |M - C2|^2 - (r1 - r2)^2 = 2 * |M - C1||M - C2|
(|M - C1|^2 + |M - C2|^2 - (r1 - r2)^2)^2 = 4 * |M - C1|^2 |M - C2|^2  (**)
```

so the medial axis is a fourth degree algebraic curve.

Let us say that `C1` and `C2` are on the y axis, and suppose that the point (0,0) lies on the medial axis (so `C1 = (0, -r1 - x)` and `C2 = (0, r2 + x)` for some `x` you can compute from your data). This is something you can always transform into.

Now, you want the curve `y = f(x)` which parametrizes the median axis. For this, pick the `x` of your choice, and solve equation `(**)` in `y` with Newton's method, with initial guess `y = 0`. This is a polynomial you can compute exactly, as well as its derivative (in `y`).

Answer (score 1):

The medial axis is in this case a hyberbola.

For more information see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Difference_of_distances_to_foci), particularly the following excerpt:

> The center of any circles externally tangent to two given circles lies on a hyperbola, whose foci are the centers of the given circles and where the vertex distance 2a equals the difference in radii of the two circles.

So the problem reduces to drawing a hyperbola, given its foci and vertex distance.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed the circles on a rectangular grid (think image), then you can use the distance transform of this image to compute your medial axis. See this [link](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm). 
Several O(nlogn) algorithms exist for computing the distance map on an image grid.